# Подключить два разных файла с одинаковым именем

Tags: c++

Подключаю два разных файла, но имена у них одинаковые. 1-ый - мой локальный, который я сам придумал, 2-ой - глобальный, видимо, из Windows SDK...

Подключаю их так, выглядит немного комично:

```
#include "anyfile.h"
#include <anyfile.h>
```

Если подход, который решит эту проблему?

Comment: Если это с++, можно попробовать использовать в своем файле другой неймспейс.

Comment: А если так `#include <../include/anyfile.h>`?

Comment: А чем вам не нравится ваше решение? Формально оно и есть решением проблемы :)

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb - а вы так уверены, что системные всегда будут в подкаталоге `include`? Могут быть варианты... Лучше так указывать не системные, а собственные файлы.

Comment: @Harry, ну я ж не знаю где его файлы:) А так да, вы правы

Comment: Если проблема исключительно в "комичности" из-за одинаковых имен, просто переименуйте свой файл.